# Sorting divs using query tinysort plugin

Tags: jquery, function, html

I am trying to use the Tinysort Jquery plugin to order a load of divs by the id of each div. Each div has an id like this :

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```

So the id is the word div followed by a number. I am currently using the following code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div").tsort("",{attr:"id"});
} );
 </script>
```

Which I grabbed from a previous Stackoverflow post and modified, but it doesn't appear to work for some reason ?.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Im not sure how you include external plugins in jsfiddle ?.

Comment: I have created a fiddle for you and it is working with your code http://jsfiddle.net/L1010/zdCyB/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/mba4c/97/

Your code is working in a jsfiddle.
Be sure to checkout the tinySort website for examples and how to specify the options.
http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

You can also use

```
tinysort("div");
```

and be done with it, because of the standard options

**External Resources**

also on jsfiddle you can use the sidebar option External Resources to include tinySort with this url i got from their github:

```
https://tinysort.sjeiti.com/dist/tinysort.min.js
```

Comment: Thanks, I have just realised that it is actually working, but the div is only wrapping part of what I need to reorder !.

Comment: I look at this in jsfiddle and I see 4, 1, 2 - unordered. Why? Something changed since this post?

Comment: Updated jsfiddle to use other external source (default from tinysort website had an invalid certificate which caused the source not to load in jsFiddle).
Working again as it should